# Integration RxJava , Retrofit 2 and Gson in Android

Tags: android, gson, rx-java, mvp, retrofit2

I begin learning mvp in android. but stuck in this problem for one day. Please help me.
I want to send username , password to login api. Server will respone json, and I will use gson to parse to Userinfo object.

This is my class RibotService

```html
public interface RibotService {

    String ENDPOINT = "https://....";
    String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";



    @POST("/login_api.php")
    Observable<Userinfo> signIn(@Body SignInRequest signInRequest);
```

This is my retrofit settings

```html
 /******** Factory class that sets up a new ribot services *******/
    class Factory {

        public static RibotService makeRibotService(Context context) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new UnauthorisedInterceptor(context));
            HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            logging.setLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                    : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
            okHttpClient.interceptors().add(logging);

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                    .create();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(RibotService.ENDPOINT)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            return retrofit.create(RibotService.class);
        }

    }
```

this is method in DataManager class

```html
  public Observable<Userinfo> signIn(final String username, final String password) {
        return mRibotService.signIn(new SignInRequest(username,password));
    }
```

I call this method in presenter

```html
 public void signInWithGoogle(final String username, String password) {
        Timber.i("Starting sign in with account " + username +"password: "+ password);
        mMvpView.showProgress(true);
//        mMvpView.setSignInButtonEnabled(false);
        mSubscription = mDataManager.signIn(username,password)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Userinfo>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.d("voz","login on completed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d("log","login on error" + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Userinfo userinfo) {
                        Log.d("log","login on next" + userinfo.getUsername());
                    }

                });

    }
```

But in the onNext method return Userinfo null, although I can see in logcat have server response from retrofit.

Thank in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to do/achieve ? You need to explain your problem and what you get.

Comment: @Ixx I want to send username , password to login api. Server will respone json, and I will use gson to parse to Userinfo object

Comment: edit your question and put the explanation there

Comment: Where is the `onNext` method, I'm not seeing that?

Comment: I think the problem is that your JSON conversion isn't working. Could you post your UserInfo definition and the JSON you get back from the server?

Comment: @JohnWowUs, thank you so much. It's because of wrong UserInfo model.